# (Delphi or C#) Re-stream MP3 chunks Live

Tags: delphi, stream, mp3, live, chunks

Please suggest the best way of live re-streaming mp3 portions. 
I am getting small blocks of mp3 file from the network (random delay and size) and have to broadcast them as continuous live stream. 
No idea what would be the best option and problems here.

Comment: C# has an extensive library collection for all types of network trafficking & buffering that support multithreaded applications.  It's also easier to find up-to-date documentation for C#.  I'm sure either language would work but I believe C# will give you more control.

Comment: Since any chunk consists 1 or more frame, the task of assembling those frames into continuous preroll buffer appears pretty trivial for me.

Comment: It is not for me, can you pleas be more specific. What components or apps shall I use to stream mp3 portions?

Comment: Note, mp3 will be generated continuously and should stream by request. Currently WinPlayer get some mp3 part, plays it and drop connection because reached end of file. I need it keep playing or wait until new mp3 part arrive